# if condition not working in javascript, when called from a textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem. `if` condition is not working in `javascript`, when called from a `textbox`.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
    function myfunction()
    {
    var x=document.getElementById("t1");
    var y=document.getElementById("t2");
    alert(x.v);
    if(x=='N' || y=='F')
    {
    alert("correct");
    }
    else
    {
    alert("wrong");
    }
    }
</script>

<div class="typing">
    <input type="text" class="typing1"  name="txt1"  id="t1" oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()">
    <input type="text" class="typing2"  name="txt2"  id="t2" oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()  onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-z]/, '')">
</div>

<div class="answer">
    <input type="image" onclick="myfunction();">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is element with id `t1` and `t2`?

Comment: Please use 'Preview' to check what your question looks like before posting it; if you format it to make it easier for other SO users to read, you will be more likely to get an answer.

Comment: You are missing a `"` in the second `input`. What is `x.v`?

Comment: {
     var x=document.getElementById("t1").value;
  var y=document.getElementById("t2").value;
  document.write(x);
  document.write(Y);

Comment: the x element is only printing not y element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to access the value of the TextBox, try this:

```
var x = document.getElementById("t1").value;
var y = document.getElementById("t2").value;
```

also change the HTML tag of "t2":

```
<input type="text" class="typing2" name="txt2" id="t2" oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-z]/, '')" />
```

Comment: i have added .value

Comment: function myfunction()
 {
     var x=document.getElementById("t1").value;
  var y=document.getElementById("t2").value;
  document.write(x);
  document.write(Y);

 if(x=='F' || y=='N')
 {
 alert("correct");
 }
 else
 {
 alert("wrong");
 }
 }
 
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" class="typing1"  name="txt1"  id="t1" >
<input type="text" class="typing1"  name="txt2"  id="t2">
<input type="image" onclick=myfunction(); src="button 60001.png" alt="Submit" width="110%" height="70%">

</body>

Comment: now when i printed the x value it is only printing x not y

Comment: You have used a Capital letter of "Y" instead of "y" in your document.write(). Use `document.write(y);`